# WordPress visual editor internal link default https

Tags: visual-editor, https

I have a WordPress site running on **`https`**. When I insert a link to another page using the Visual Editor it defaults to **`http`**.

Can i change this somewhere?

The closes thing i could find is [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7794):
In my case I would than need to replace **`http:`** to **`https:`**, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: Does your site URL in Settings > General use https? That's where the URL comes from.

Comment: if u provide it as answer ill accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your URL in *Settings > General* uses `https://`. That's where the URL comes from.